# Convert Storyboard to XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

I created an app using the iOS 5 Storyboard feature, and have decided I would like it to also run on iOS 4. How can I convert my Storyboard (Which only contains one ViewController) into an XIB? Also, will ARC compile for iOS 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is an automatic way to go from storyboard to xib.  i think you will need to make the nibs and copy paste.

ARC will run on iOS 4.  The compiler inserts the necessary extra code to free memory for you. ARC works from 4.0 on.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to avoid copy an paste (I have more than 50 objects!), but I guess it will be fine.

Comment: The copy-paste method works great for most views but I ran into an issue where I had a table view in my storyboard that had embedded sections and cells. I received the following compiler error: "Table views with embedded sections and cells are only supported in storyboard documents".